# ¿Cuándo y cómo apareció el término "mieditis"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, sustantivos

Hoy me he encontrado en el diccionario una de esas palabras que parece que son de broma pero resulta que están registradas:

> **[mieditis](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PDCusbv)**
>
> 1. f. coloq. miedo.

Buscando en el CORDE veo que aparecen casos desde finales del siglo XIX, cosa que parece confirmar [la gráfica de NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mieditis&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1850&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmieditis%3B%2Cc0). Sin embargo, ¿se sabe cuándo y cómo surgió el término?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El 1 de mayo de 1855 arrancó el periódico satírico *Fray Tinieblas*, editado y publicado en Madrid. Este periódico usaba un estilo un tanto agresivo hacia sus competidores, más cautos, y no tardó mucho en acusarles de padecer una epidemia que bautizaron con el nombre de *mieditis*, usando el sufijo *[-itis](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MESHpdR)* como en *otitis* o *laringitis*, que literalmente significa "inflamación" pero da a entender simplemente el concepto de "enfermedad".

Os dejo uno de sus casos, muy ilustrativo:

> La ESCUADRA de *oposicion*, se va de volina, á la capa, desde aquello que se acordó en pleno Congreso á bordo de la GOLETA *Asamblea*, sobre la suspension de las *garantías constitucionales*, aunque se van ya volviendo agua de borrajas lo de las tales garantías: sin embargo, se observa con gusto por acá que nuestro VAPOR FRAY-TINIEBLAS, no cede ni por esas, y que cada dia mas firme embiste con doble fuerza: sin duda no padece la epidemia que los demás buques periodistas, conocida con el nombre de *Mieditis* ó *Canguelo*.
>
> Fray Tinieblas. 25/6/1855, n.º 12, página 3.

Curioso que al final dicha publicación no superara los 25 números, finalizando su andadura el 10 de septiembre del mismo año 1855. Al menos su inventiva consiguió dejarnos como recuerdo una entrada en el diccionario.

Answer (score 2):

> 7.2. *Aproximación metafórica a nivel de patrón*
>
> En el apartado anterior hemos visto casos en los cuales el educto ha sido mantenido constante, pero se observan licencias con la base o la relación base-derivado, que luego desata una interpretación figurativa (en nuestro caso, metafórica). Si se trata solo de desviaciones aisladas motivadas por razones estilísticas o retóricas, no podemos hablar de cambio lingüístico a nivel de sistema. Para que podamos hablar de un cambio del sistema lexicogenésico, tiene que producirse un paso más, es decir, que algunas formaciones estilísticas de este tipo se establezcan definitivamente en la lengua y den lugar a nuevas creaciones directamente sobre el modelo de estas formaciones.
>
> Un caso de este tipo está constituido por **el uso figurativo del sufijo *-itis* en varias lenguas europeas.** Como es sabido, la función primaria de este sufijo en las lenguas modernas es la de designar inflamaciones en el lenguaje médico: *faringitis* `inflamación de la faringe', *amigdalitis* 'inflamación de las amígdalas', etc. Ahora bien, **en algún momento hacia mediados del siglo XIX, en una lengua que todavía no ha sido identificada con certeza** (cf sobre el italiano Schweickard 1993 y sobre el alemán Lüdeling & Evert 2005), **se le ocurrió a algún hablante creativo aplicar este modelo a fenómenos que se pueden categorizar como inflamaciones o más bien enfermedades solo en sentido figurativo. El ejemplo español más antiguo que me consta es el siguiente de *mieditis* de 1859:**
>
> > `Dav.` Otra vez, heraldos, suene
> >     De las trompetas el kco.
> >
> > *(Suenan las trompetas.)*
> >
> > `Fri.` Ya nadie el combate acepta.
> >
> > `Gun.` Terrible, Friga, se ha hecho.
> >
> > `Dav.` Repetid el desafío!
> >     Heraldos, último reto!
> >
> > *(Suenan las trompetas.)*
> >
> > `Bé.` En vano las trompetas suenan,
> >     Hay *un mieditis superbo.* [cursiva en el original]
>
> (Rafael Leopoldo de Palomino, [*Omunda. Drama en cinco cuadros*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=x2wvAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA52&dq="mieditis"), Habana: La Charanga, 1859, p. 52).
>
> **En este paso, *mieditis* (usado al masculino, como *miedo*, mientras hoy el género está determinado por la serie médica) se usa para elevar d miedo a la categoría de enfermedad y provocar así un efecto lúdico. La novedad de tal manera de expresarse en el momento de imprimirse el texto está probada por el uso de la cursiva.** Más tarde, este uso figurativo de *-itis* se ha convertido en un patrón convencional y muy productivo: *telefonitis* 'afición desmesurada al uso del teléfono', *franquitis* 'nostalgia por Franco', *encuestitis* 'recurso excesivo a encuestas', etc. Hoy en día, el sistema lexicogenésico del español como el de las demás lenguas europeas, contiene dos sufijos *-itis*, que están relacionados todavía por una relación metafórica transparente, pero independientes, como prueban las diferencias en el significado del educto (Inflamación' *vs.* 'enfermedad metafórica, afición exagerada'), la relación semántica entre base y sufijo (invariablemente 'inflamación de N' en el uno, pero muy variada en el segundo), en el ámbito de uso (dis-curso médico *vs.* lenguaje periodístico o lúdico en general), el tipo de bases (partes del cuerpo u órganos *vs.* quodlibet), etc.
>
> - [*Formación de palabras y analogía*](https://datospdf.com/download/formacion-de-palabras-y-analogia-_5a4c3aa5b7d7bcb74fea9d27_pdf), Franz Rainer (p.165-166)

Comment: Menos mal que el caso más antiguo que le consta al autor (Franz Rainer) no es anterior a 1855, o me habrías desmontado mi respuesta. Quizá el "hablante creativo" del que habla sea el escritor de "Fray Tinieblas".

Comment: @Charlie sí, pensé que merecería la pena subir esta cita por el comentario sobre la origen de tal uso de *-itis*, incluso si no es el ejemplo *más* antiguo.